# article style page layout in book class only for one page

Tags: books

`book` class arranges the text as it is required for printing. The margins are set automatically. If we don't want that formatting, `oneside` option is available, but it changes the formatting of the document globally. I just want the `titlepage` environment of the document like it is in the `article` class. It should be horizontally centered like in the `article` class. It should also be vertically centered like in the `book` class. After exploring some answers on this site, I tried `afterpage` package, but didn't find it helpful. Can somebody help me to redefine `titlepage` environment?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\author{Niranjan}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `geometry` package, you can control the page geometry, and use its `savegeometry` and `\newgeometry` command to locally change the titlepage geometry. The `\layout` command of eponymous package and the `showframe` option  of `geometry` can help for a proper setting of the margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\author{Niranjan}

\newlength{\shift} \setlength{\shift}{0.2in}
\begin{document}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{\shift} % shift text to the right
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-\shift} % shift text back to the left
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The shift value of 0.2in looked OK to me but you may want to change it a little bit.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked.